# when run the project shows error: incompatible types

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

when run the project shows two error
1.error: incompatible types: sample.controller.Details cannot be converted to sample.dao.Details
stDao.save(ei);
2.error: incompatible types: sample.controller.Details cannot be converted to sample.dao.Details
stDao.update(st);

i give the two class files  below

this is studentController.java file

```
  package sample.controller;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import sample.dao.studentDao;
    @Controller
    public class studentController {
          @Autowired
        studentDao stDao;
         @RequestMapping(value ="index.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String index()
        {
            System.out.println("at index");
            return "index";
        }
        
        @RequestMapping(value ="insert.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody String insert
            (
                @RequestParam("id") Integer id,
                @RequestParam("name") String name,
                @RequestParam("email") String email,
                @RequestParam("fee") String fee,
                  @RequestParam("sname") String sname,
                  @RequestParam("contactno") String contactno
            )
      
            {
    
            Details ei;
            ei = new Details();
            ei.setName(name);
            ei.setEmail(email);
            ei.setFee(fee);
            ei.setSname(sname);
            ei.setContactno(contactno);
           stDao.save(ei);
     Gson ob = new Gson();
            return "success";
       }
        
     @RequestMapping(value="fetch.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String display() 
        {
            List<Details> listdetails = (List<Details>) stDao.display();
            return new Gson().toJson(listdetails);
        }
    
        
        @RequestMapping(value = "delete.htm")
        public @ResponseBody  String delete(@RequestParam("id") Integer id)
        {
            stDao.delete(id);
            return "successful";
        }
        
        @RequestMapping(value = "edit.htm")
        public @ResponseBody  String edit(@RequestParam("id") Integer id)
        {
            List editlist;
            editlist = stDao.getDetailsForEdit(id);
            return new Gson().toJson(editlist);
        }
        
        
        @RequestMapping(value = "update.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody String update
            (
                @RequestParam(value="id",required=false) Integer id,
                @RequestParam("name") String name,
                @RequestParam("email") String email,
                @RequestParam("fee") String fee,
                @RequestParam("sname") String sname,
                @RequestParam("contactno") String contactno
           )
            {
                
            Details st = new Details();
            st.setName(name);
            st.setEmail(email);
            st.setFee(fee);
            st.setSname(sname);
            st.setContactno(contactno);
            System.out.println("st");
            stDao.update(st);
            Gson ob = new Gson();
            return "success";
        }
    }
    
this studentDao.java file

package sample.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projections;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class studentDao {

   @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public void save(Details stdinfo) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(stdinfo);
        session.close();
    }
public List display() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Details.class);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
                .add(Projections.property("name"), "name")
                .add(Projections.property("email"), "email")
                .add(Projections.property("fee"), "fee") 
                .add(Projections.property("sname"), "sname") 
                .add(Projections.property("contactno"), "contactno"));
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        List list = criteria.list();
        session.close();
        return list;
    }    
     public void delete(Integer id){
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction trx = session.beginTransaction();
        Details stdtl = new Details(id);
        session.delete(stdtl);
        trx.commit();
        session.close();
    } 
     public List getDetailsForEdit(Integer id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Details.class);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
                .add(Projections.property("name"), "name")
                .add(Projections.property("email"), "email")
                       .add(Projections.property("fee"), "fee")
                       .add(Projections.property("sname"), "sname")
                .add(Projections.property("contactno"), "contactno")
        );
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        List list = criteria.list();
        session.close();
        return list;
    }
    public void update(Details Stdinfo){
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction trx = session.beginTransaction();        
        session.update(Stdinfo);
        trx.commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

}

Comment: It looks like you've got two different classes called `Details`, in two different packages, and you're getting confused about which one's which.  I would suggest giving them different names, which should make it clearer how to fix the problem.

Comment: ok thank you  when changing class name program run.